# Keybinding to launch another terminal rather than gnome-shell

Tags: gnome

The 'gnome-shell-terminal` is bonded with 'Ctrl + Alt + T"

[image]

I work on alacritty substitute for `gnome-shell-terminal` daily.

How could config the key-binding to alacritty?

Comment: do you know the command to open alacritty?? then first disable ctrl alt t for launch terminal and then create shortcut for alacritty with ctrl alt T

Comment: I strike "super' key and click in from the search bar, there's no such a key-binding. @PRATAP

Comment: ok let me try.. can you tell me how to install alacritty

Comment: `add-apt-repository ppa:mmstick76/alacritty; and pip install alacritty' @PRATAP  [jwilm/alacritty: A cross-platform, GPU-accelerated terminal emulator](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty) thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` and choose the number that corresponds with your favorite terminal-emulator.

Example:

```
parrot@i7-4770U:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
[sudo] password for parrot: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/alacritty                20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/alacritty to provide /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator (x-terminal-emulator) in manual mode
parrot@i7-4770U:~$
```

This is automatically bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: ty very very much , amazing.

Comment: @PRATAP are you sure that works? The terminal emulator invoked by that shortcut was hardcoded in the past.